# how to get string between .ism and slash before it using php?

Tags: php, substr, strpos

I have a large string and want to extract data between `.ism` and the slash `/` before it. For example I want to get: `life-episode-galaxy`

My current code gives all data before `.ism`. Could anyone tell me what is wrong here and how to get only data between `.ism` and slash `/` before it?

```
<?

$code="media=http://somesite.com/4534543kjlkljklkjlkkljlkdsfsfo/life-episode-galaxy.ism/manifest,deliverymethod=adaptiv";
$startsAt3 = strpos($code, "/") + strlen("/");
$endsAt3 = strpos($code, ".ism", $startsAt3);
$result3 = substr($code, $startsAt3, $endsAt3 - $startsAt3);

echo $result3;

?>
```

Comment: You can use preg_match then remove the .ism from matched element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Assume your link would have always the same number of slashes `/` you can just explode into an array and output the right element, removing the not needed data with `str_replace`

```
$code="media=http://somesite.com/4534543kjlkljklkjlkkljlkdsfsfo/life-episode-galaxy.ism/manifest,deliverymethod=adaptiv";
$array = explode("/", str_replace("//", "/", $code));
echo str_replace('.ism', '', $array[3]);
```

This will output

```
life-episode-galaxy
```

#### [Live Sample](http://ideone.com/AF4j0x)

Comment: How is your solution different from `substr($code, 50, 61)`? _(numbers not checked)_

Comment: That's why I assumed the number of slashes would be always the same

Comment: many thanks all. fabio your solution worked well as you said the number of slashes before .ism are fixed!

Answer (score 1):

You could use a regexp, but that's boring.

You can use [`strrpos`](http://php.net/strrpos) with the 3rd `offset` parameter, using a negative offset.

```
$ism_pos = strpos($code, ".ism");
$last_slash_pos_before_ism = strrpos($code, "/", $ism_pos - strlen($code));
$result = substr($code, $last_slash_pos_before_ism, $ism_pos);
```

Might be off-by-one here and there, check it.

Comment: So why is regex boring?  Though I don't dispute that your approach works (and might actually be faster than regex), I would submit that the intent of the code is much clearer using the regex than with using basic string manipulations.

Comment: I see too many instances where regexps are used where a simple `strpos` would suffice. _"if all you have is a hammer, everything looks like a nail"_. There is of course also the performance penalty, but usually that doesn't really matter.

Answer (score 1):

I would use regex:

```
$pattern = '#/(.*)\.ism/#U';
$matches = array();
$found = preg_match($pattern, $string, $matches);
if (1 === $found) {
    $your_desired_string = $matches[1];
} else {
    // not found
}
```

Comment: @HighKickX No. `$matches[0]` would contain the entire matching portion of the string `$matches[1]` would contain the first sub-pattern capture from the match.